# What's wrong with my log file generation?

Tags: grep, tail

I'd like to capture and filter the logs from my ESP32 peripheral from the serial port and generate a new log file with the selected line.
I do as follows:

```bash
$ (((stty speed 115200  && cat) </dev/cu.usbserial-14101) | grep "Final SoC is") >> ~/extremeCold.20220926.log
```

In parallel, in another terminal window, I monitor the generation with a tail as follows:

```bash
tail -f ~/extremeCold.20220926.log
```

Though the peripheral logs are streaming at constant speed, I noticed the tail produces a first set of lines to eventually halt.